# What's the problem-solving tag supposed to be about?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Just noticed the [problem-solving](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving) tag, which seems to be frequently misused.  I understood it to mean "this question is about helping kids learn to solve their problems" as in [Any advice on how to react to my 4 year old who gets hysterical instead of solving her "problem"?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/6940/any-advice-on-how-to-react-to-my-4-year-old-who-gets-hysterical-instead-of-solvi) and [Teaching logic and problem solving to children?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8804/teaching-logic-and-problem-solving-to-children), but it seems to be being misused to mean "this question is about a problem I'm trying to solve," which really describes most every question on the site.

I have edited [here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/11262/extremely-fussy-and-refusing-to-sleep-12-week-old), [here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7268/do-babies-who-watch-tv-start-speaking-late), and [here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7137/those-babies-who-start-walking-early-will-start-talking-late) to remove the improper usages and added a tag wiki.  Since it's misused as often as properly used, should it be banned, and a better synonym created for the correct usage?  If so, what should the synonym be?  Or have I got it wrong, and the connotation I perceived as misuse should actually be supported?

**Edit:** There seemed to be a pretty good consensus on using [problem-solving-skills](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving-skills) instead, so I made the change.

Comment: That's why I added the [meta-tag:status-completed].  Good idea about accepting an answer, though.

Comment: That's actually what drove me to confusion - it took me a while to figure out what the 'completed' action was :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose to rename it [problem-solving-skills](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving-skills) as per [Jeremy Miller's suggestion](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/qu-stions/628#comment-1151).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it makes any sense for 'problem solving' to mean 'I have a problem, help me solve it', since that's what *all* of StackExchange is about.  I think it makes sense as "problem-solving skills", as you have interpreted it.

I'm not even sure the first question you linked (the 4 year old tantrum question) makes sense there - it's not really about 'problem solving' either, though perhaps that's splitting hairs.  To me, it would be questions like the second question: problem solving as in the logical/deductive reasoning skill.

Comment: I favor renaming  it problem solving skills.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with your interpretation (and Joe's) of the tag.  If we wanted to get rid of "problem solving" altogether though:

Critical Thinking skills and Problem solving are closely related.  Perhaps a replacement tag related to critical thinking?